# How to join two words together

Tags: ruby

I am creating topics with fields: title, hashtags, and keywords. For hashtags, users will pass words with `'#'` like `'#book #author '`. If a user passes a word without `'#'` like `'#book author'`, then `'author'` should be joined with `'book'` like `'#bookauthor'`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You want it to end as #bookauthor or #book#author ?

Comment: i want it as #bookauthor

Comment: `str.gsub(/ +(?!#)/, '')`. `(?!#)` is a *negative lookahead*. It prevents a space from being replaced by an empty string if it is followed immediately by a pound sign.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove any spaces from your string (which is what I think you want), then try:

```
string.delete(' ')

'#book author'.delete(' ') => '#bookauthor'
```

Comment: but what if user type with comma like "#book , author"?

Comment: You didn't ask about a comma. Is there a list of characters you want to delete....?

Comment: @ShahrozAshraf seems like you didn't specify your problem thoroughly. Edit your question and add the relevant details. Provide some examples if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it:

```rb
def parse_tags(tags)
    tags.scan(/#[^#]+/).map {|tag| tag.delete(' ') }
end
```

This scans for tags and removes all white spaces between words in them.

```
parse_tags("#book #author") # => ["#book", "#author"]
parse_tags("#book author")  # => ["#bookauthor"]
```

Comment: if user puts ',' between words like "#book , author" than??

Comment: @ShahrozAshraf You haven't provided such example in your question. If you have other cases in mind, the question needs to be more specific and complete.

Comment: You can add more characters to the `delete` parameter, like this: `tag.delete(' ,')`. If you want only alphanumerical characters on your tags, then `tag.gsub(/[^\w\d]/,"")` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I think he wants hashtags too but his requirements seem to change every comment... good luck.

Comment: In Ruby method returns its last line, so `def method; :smth end` is equal to `def method; return :smth end`. Codestyle [recommends](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#no-explicit-return) to avoid such `return`